# svn print the owner of working copy who did the checkout

Tags: svn

How to print the owner of the working copy. ie. the name of the authorized account owner who did the checkout.

EDIT:- I have to checkout a huge repository(about 2 Gb) from a very slow svn server. So i thought i can copy the existing working copy of my co-worker and make changes to it and then commit the code. Just want to make sure that the credentials are not stored in the working copy and the code is not committed on the name of the owner who did the checkout.

Comment: There is no requirement in svn to track working copies. Svn is not capable of this. You may want to clarify your question to describe the task you want to complete. The current question can be answered just with "NO, YOU CAN'T and YOU DON'T NEED THIS".

Comment: On Windows simple `dir /q WorkingCopy\.svn\wc.db` can do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for? Did someone checkout a working directory, and you see the working directory and you want to see who owns it? Are you trying to find who has what files checked out? Are you sharing your working directories, so you don't know who made the modifications? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: Sharing working directories sounds more dangerous than sharing needles

Comment: @Cole9350: Why is it ?

Comment: @Talespin because it contradicts the entire point to using SVN in the first place .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477901/several-developers-and-one-subversions-working-folder

Answer (score 0):

Subversion working copy is a private workspace for everyone who has access to the repository and projects stored in it. Subversion servers do not track who and when did the checkout and they don't track the status of user's working copy in any way. Why do you want this?

The only possibility to track who did the `svn checkout` or `svn export` is [to analyze Subversion access log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html).